# CSS question, how do change border position?

Tags: html, css

So basically, this is what it looks like: https://gyazo.com/1ef3172636a230539dcb850677a9cc21

But I want to achieve this: https://gyazo.com/b2b836fa858b501ff0d9f3131eb54630

The border of the image in the one I want to replicate, the border is showing more on the top and less at the bottom (just enough to fit a caption) how do I go about that?

````
<main id="main">

    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #e2e2e2;
        }

        #title {
            font-size: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            min-width: 500px;
        }

        #tribute-info {
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            min-width: 500px;
        }
    </style>

    <h1 id="title">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1>
    <h2 id="tribute-info">The man who saved a billion lives</h2>
    <style>
        #image {
            max-width: 80%;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 100px;
            border-color: white;
            border-position: 25px;

        }
    </style>

    <a id="tribute-link" target="_blank"
        href="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/mrz1e/s1/coolest-cars-feature.jpg">Click me </a>
    <div id="img-div">
        <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5d09594a62bcb0c9752779d9/1:1/w_1500,h_1500,c_limit/Transpo_G70_TA-518126.jpg"
            alt="A car" id="image">
        <figcaption id="img-caption">A bad ass car</figcaption>
    </div>

</main>```
````

Answer (score 0):

To have different widths for the different sides of the border, use styles like this: `border-top-width: 150px;`

```html
<main id="main">

    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #e2e2e2;
        }

        #title {
            font-size: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            min-width: 500px;
        }

        #tribute-info {
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            min-width: 500px;
        }
    </style>

    <h1 id="title">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1>
    <h2 id="tribute-info">The man who saved a billion lives</h2>
    <style>
        #image {
            max-width: 80%;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            border-style: solid;
            border-top-width: 150px;
            border-left-width: 100px;
            border-right-width: 100px;
            border-bottom-width: 50px;
            border-color: white;
            border-position: 25px;

        }
    </style>

    <a id="tribute-link" target="_blank"
        href="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/mrz1e/s1/coolest-cars-feature.jpg">Click me </a>
    <div id="img-div">
        <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5d09594a62bcb0c9752779d9/1:1/w_1500,h_1500,c_limit/Transpo_G70_TA-518126.jpg"
            alt="A car" id="image">
        <figcaption id="img-caption">A bad ass car</figcaption>
    </div>

</main>
```

Comment: If you're going to use border-width, you can set all sides in one declaration like: `border-width: 150px 100px 50px;` (setting top, sides, and bottom.)